# Java or scala, GeoTools or GeoTrellis, how to convert sentinel 2 data to Multiband geotif

Tags: raster, geotools, geotiff, geotrellis

I am trying to process Sentinel 2 data from (example)

http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/#tiles/10/S/EG/2016/10/12/0/

The jp2 files are not georeferenced, and I need to put all the jp2 files as bands in a geotif. I have googled aplenty and find no way to do this in Java or Scala.

I am pretty familiar with Geotools, i've done a lot of geotif processing with geotools, but I can't figure out how to

a. Make a geotif raster out of a jp2 file (given coords for the envelope), and

b. take those and make a multiband geotif out of them

I am decent with Scala, so I've looked at geotrellis, but don't see a solution with that either.

Does anyone know how to make geotifs out of JP2 files (given a polygon) and then make a multiband geotif?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried this, but, I would break the problem down to:

1. Import JP2 image
2. GeoReference the image
3. For each band in the image data, convert to GeoTiff

Step 1 will need you to make sure that you have the [JP2K plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/jp2k.html), that page also gives some sample code showing how to use it.

Step 2 should just be a case of building a `GridCoverage` using a `GridCoverageFactory` - see the [user guide for an example](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/grid.html) (I am assuming you know where the bounds of the grid are and it's projection etc).

Step 3 is a simple [`CoverageWriter`](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/coverage/grid/GridCoverageWriter.html), there is an [example here](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/coverage/coverage.html).

Comment: This is a good answer, I'm going to mark it as such, but I ended up just using the GDAL Java/Scala bindings to solve this